# Is there any way to export Code Generator TOTP key for use with Google Authenticator app?

Tags: facebook, security

I've enabled the FB Code Generator (one-time passwords for secure login on new devices). I've already got 5 other accounts set up in Google Authenticator, so it'd be great if I could export my FB otp key for use in that app.

Between simulators, browsers, and test devices, I actually have to use this pretty often. It's kinda annoying that I have to start the FB app, tap the menu, scroll to the bottom of the huge list, and tap code generator (at least 5 seconds from a cold start)... When I can pull up the Google Authenticator app in approximately half a second.

Barring the ability to export keys, is there at least some way I can set my TOTP key via the API or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Facebook uses the standard TOTP algorithm and will need to accommodate the use case where you didn't have mobile internet access (hence key/seed fetching unavailable).

Look for the "having trouble?" link in the popped up dialog in your browser when setting up code generator, it will lead you to a seed/key. Just feed that into your Google Authenticator and verify the first code, it should work :)

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I wasn't able to get this method to work, but it led me to look on the website again where I found it under Settings > Security > Code Generator > Set up -- https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=code_generator&view

This definitely wasn't there when I asked, but I'll accept you anyway!